Boots into grub2; how to fix so it boots into any OS?
Was installing Arch. Made a simple boot partition + home partition setup, but upon boot it goes to Grub. Attempted to set root and use chainloader to boot from grub, but it does nothing when running boot command. How to get this computer back to booting on any OS? I know if I go to a local shop they'll reinstall windows with a usb and bring it back, but I just want to do that at home without paying a fee.
Details: Running ls with or without a USB (with other ISO (linux or windows)) shows the same things: (hd0-2). Hd0 has gpt1-2 the first containing the /efi/grub/grubx64.efi file. The second is in ext3/4 format (it doesn't say and I'm not sure which). I tried setting either gpt1/2 as root prior to boot but it doesn't work.

Did your computer have Windows on it before? Are you trying to dual-boot or just run Arch on this computer? GRUB is a normal part of most Linux installs so it's normal to see GRUB after installing Linux. Is the issue that it doesn't get past GRUB and load Arch, or something else?

Windows before. Tried to just install Arch only. It doesn't get past grub2, it's there upon boot and expecting grub input.

It sounds like your computer is booting to the GRUB Recovery Environment, aka the GRUB command line. This is either because you never configured GRUB when installing Arch or because you misconfigured it. GRUB can't find the kernel it's supposed to automatically load, so it dumps you into a command line environment where you can try to load the kernel yourself.
There are ways to recover from a bad GRUB setup: either by manually loading the kernel from the recovery prompt, or with a live USB. However, since your install is new, I would suggest reinstalling Arch, making sure to generate a GRUB config as mentioned here:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#Generate_the_main_configuration_file
If you already tried following those instructions, but you still ended up at the recovery prompt when rebooting, let us know some more specifics about your setup and what commands you ran.

As far as booting from a USB goes, tap your PC manufacturer's "BIOS boot menu" key (usually F12, Enter, or ESC) during early boot to get to a boot menu, then select the USB there. If you're at a GRUB prompt, it's too late and you're already booting from the wrong device (hard drive). Hard reboot and try again.
